# following code is to generate a web form using html,expressJS and save submitted details in mongodb but there is 'post' error and 'get' works

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose

the 'post' is working from the postman and creating a document with object id in the database when I go to localhost:3000 in the browser and type the entries(name, email, address) and hit submit button, it says unable to save and not creating an object in mongo database.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>formReg</title>

</head>
     <body>

        <form name='regForm' method ='post' action ='/add'>
          username: <input type='text' name='username' required/><br>
          email: <input type='email' name='email' required/><br>
          address: <textarea rows='5' col='10' name='address'></textarea><br>
          <button type ='submit' value='submit'>submit</button>
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

This code is to interact with database, html.

```
 var express = require("express");


 var app = express();
 var port = 3000;

 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

 var mongoose =require('mongoose');
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-user');

 var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: {type: String, unique: true},
   email:{type: String},
   address:{type: String}
 });

 var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

 app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile(__dirname+'/form1.html');

 });

app.post('/add', (req, res)=>{

  var username= req.body.username;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var address = req.body.address;

  var myData = new User();
  myData.username = username;
  myData.email = email;
  myData.address = address;

  myData.save().then((item)=>{
    res.send('item saved');
  },(err)=>{
    res.status(400).send('unable to save');
  });
});
 app.listen(port, ()=>{
   console.log("server is on port "+port);
 })
```

Comment: Hi neil, i am using mongodb to connect to local host:27017.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that I see here:

1. The form field name is 'userName' but the mongoose model field name is 'username'
2. The address textarea does not have a `name` attribute (`name="address"`), so it's not submitted in the form.

Comment: thanks for that, but still i am getting the 'unable to save' in browser. But works when i gave json details in postman and selecting post with address: htpp://localhost:3000/add